# On-demand Nvidia Prime GPU switching on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg, nvidia-settings

I recently tried latest Ubuntu release(19.10) and found that it's the only system(among Linux systems) with present support of on-demand GPU switching, but as I find Ubuntu not the best distro, I was wondering, what system components(except NVidia driver, which in my case is version 435) should I upgrade to obtain on-demand GPU switching using NVidia Prime feature on my Linux Mint 19.3(based on Ubuntu 18.04) and where to get all brand-new components, not available from default repos? I have hybrid graphics in my laptop consisting of Intel(UHD Graphics 620) integrated GPU and NVidia(GeForce MX150) discrete GPU

Comment: Any distro where you can install the Nvidia drivers will have that feature.

Comment: No. NVidia Prime can offer manual GPU switching which, in fact, requires logging out and then back, logging in to your user(or restarting x11 subsystem). On-demand GPU switching in NVidia Prime means that you don't need to do this, and system is able to switch GPUs on the go without logging out and in to switch cards

Comment: I didn't know Ubuntu could do that. Last time I checked it didn't, reboot was necessary (sorry for misunderstanding your question). I guess if did changed that would be news and I haven't read anything of that sort. Can you give a link where that new feature is mentioned?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2019/10/23/ubuntu-mate-1910-has-two-awesome-new-features-for-linux-users/amp/
Here it is. It mentions only MATE, but I can confirm that it works in Gnome(or any other DE)as well

Comment: Many thanks :) That is undoubtedly good news but the article mentions it being a feature of Nvidia 435 driver so I guess it should work in any Linux where it can be installed and has graphics new enough to be supported by that driver version.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have already installed driver v.435, but there are still no "NVidia on-demand" option

Comment: Well, it can also have something to do with the kernel version that's newer in 19.10. Other than that I can't imagine Ubuntu having anything so special that can't be available in derivatives like Mint. I don't use Mint - hate it - so I don't follow their releases but if there's one based on Ubuntu 19.10 then, given the same conditions, what you want must work there too.